# FInding the hard disk storage capacity programmatically

Tags: hard-drive, data-storage

How do I find out the storage capacity of my harddisk without using the OS functions like dir or ls?

Comment: Are you really looking for an OS-agnostic, language-agnostic answer? If not, please provide us with info on the programming language and IDE and OS.

Comment: Total capacity or available capacity? What Platform? What Language? The more data you input to SO, the better results you get.

Comment: The programming language used is C. IDE is Watcom or Turbo C. Sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: And the OS is, say, windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows:

Win32: [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28VS.85%29.aspx)

.NET:  [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx)

If, for whatever reason, you still don't want to use those, you can [send an IOCTL message direct to the disk driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365178%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The DriveInfo was what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[`statfs()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html) unix system call is your friend (link points to BSD man page as used in Mac OS X).